# Run 2005 Windows XP game

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, virtualbox, gaming, dll

I have a [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/kjy9ku/help_booting_old_game/) post on it, but will go over my issue again.

I have this 2005 game (bet on soldier: black-out saigon) that requires the following:

[image]

I have solved some dll missing problems and I have set up a virtualbox with Windows XP to try and play this game and I just can't. I'll probably get tired of playing within 5 minutes, but this issue is tilting me and I want to solve it and to know why it's happening at all.

For windows 10, it prompts the following:

[image]

For windows XP, similar error but slightly different:
[image]

I tried compatibility mode in windows 10 too, not solved.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? I fixed the other .dll problems but this one was spawned by satan or something because it just refuses to work.

EDIT: Set the game in W10 to launch with DirectX9, but still same error.

EDIT 2:Tried on an x32 Windows XP virtual machine, with all the .dll and DirectX9, and I still get the "Kt_Game.dll failed to Initialize" error, although now after closing this propmpt I get the "send info" prompt, which I didn't before:
[image]

Here is the error output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="BoS.exe" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Bos.dll" SIZE="2822144" CHECKSUM="0x9E60ACFF" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="12/22/2006 11:26:27" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/22/2006 11:26:27" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="BoS.exe" SIZE="16384" CHECKSUM="0xCFBE25EC" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="12/22/2006 11:26:34" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/22/2006 11:26:34" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="d3dx9_25.dll" SIZE="3823312" CHECKSUM="0x1A33AF9E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.6.168.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.6.168.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="9.06.168.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® DirectX for Windows®" FILE_VERSION="9.06.168.0000" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="D3DX9D.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="D3DX9D.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x3AC5CF" LINKER_VERSION="0x50002" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.6.168.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.6.168.0" LINK_DATE="03/19/2005 00:17:08" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/19/2005 00:17:08" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="d3dx9_29.dll" SIZE="3830992" CHECKSUM="0xD1801C01" BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.11.519.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.11.519.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="9.11.519.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® DirectX for Windows®" FILE_VERSION="9.11.519.0000" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="D3DX9D.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="D3DX9D.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x3AF83F" LINKER_VERSION="0x50002" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.11.519.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.11.519.0" LINK_DATE="02/03/2006 15:43:44" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/03/2006 15:43:44" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kte_core.dll" SIZE="1265664" CHECKSUM="0x6DE8ABD6" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Core Classes" COMPANY_NAME="Kilotonn" PRODUCT_NAME="Kt Engine" FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kte_core.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="kte_core.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Kilotonn." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x10001" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:55:26" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:55:26" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kte_dx9.dll" SIZE="1085440" CHECKSUM="0x2C9F827A" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" FILE_DESCRIPTION="DirectX 9 Overload Classes" COMPANY_NAME="Kilotonn" PRODUCT_NAME="Kt Engine" FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kte_dx9.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="kte_dx9.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Kilotonn." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x10001" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:57:49" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:57:49" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kte_sound.dll" SIZE="315392" CHECKSUM="0x487209FD" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Sound System Classes" COMPANY_NAME="Kilotonn" PRODUCT_NAME="Kt Engine" FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kte_sound.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="kte_sound.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Kilotonn." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x10001" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:57:01" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:57:01" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kte_sound_ds9.dll" SIZE="88576" CHECKSUM="0xBFF72326" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" FILE_DESCRIPTION="DirectX 9 Overload Classes" COMPANY_NAME="Kilotonn" PRODUCT_NAME="Kt Engine" FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kte_sound_ds9.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="kte_sound_ds9.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Kilotonn." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x10001" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:57:48" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:57:48" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kte_tools.dll" SIZE="741376" CHECKSUM="0x66B4196E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tool Classes" COMPANY_NAME="Kilotonn" PRODUCT_NAME="Kt Engine" FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kte_tools.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="kte_tools.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Kilotonn." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x10001" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.3.109.214" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.3.109.214" LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:57:34" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/18/2006 13:57:34" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="KT_Game.dll" SIZE="2215936" CHECKSUM="0x34ADF101" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="12/22/2006 11:24:29" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/22/2006 11:24:29" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="msvcp71.dll" SIZE="503808" CHECKSUM="0x7F6A1FCC" BIN_FILE_VERSION="7.10.6052.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.10.6052.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="7.10.6052.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Microsoft® C++ Runtime Library" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Visual Studio .NET" FILE_VERSION="7.10.6052.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="MSVCP71.DLL" INTERNAL_NAME="MSVCP71.DLL" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x84E3D" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="7.10.6052.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.10.6052.0" LINK_DATE="02/02/2007 04:13:04" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/02/2007 04:13:04" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="msvcr71.dll" SIZE="344064" CHECKSUM="0x76D04BA9" BIN_FILE_VERSION="7.10.7031.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.10.7031.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="7.10.7031.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Microsoft® C Runtime Library" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Visual Studio .NET" FILE_VERSION="7.10.7031.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="MSVCR71.DLL" INTERNAL_NAME="MSVCR71.DLL" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x5FA93" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="7.10.7031.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.10.7031.4" LINK_DATE="02/02/2007 01:11:16" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/02/2007 01:11:16" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="msvcr71d.dll" SIZE="544768" CHECKSUM="0x9F267F8D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="7.10.6030.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.10.6030.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="7.10.6030.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Microsoft® C Runtime Library" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Visual Studio .NET" FILE_VERSION="7.10.6030.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="MSVCR71D.DLL" INTERNAL_NAME="MSVCR71D.DLL" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x8DC86" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="7.10.6030.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.10.6030.0" LINK_DATE="07/12/2006 01:06:29" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/12/2006 01:06:29" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="PhysX-9.13.0604-SystemSoftware-Legacy.msi" SIZE="20154368" CHECKSUM="0x881B08E4" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="989696" CHECKSUM="0x7D737C09" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-2111)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xF44A2" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:11:24" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:11:24" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

There is a .dmp file too, but no idea what it is or how to use it to get any info.

Comment: Did you load all 3 service packs into XP? XP should be SP 3

Comment: I currently have SP2 in my Windows XP x64 virtual machine. According to some forums, there is no SP3 for x64 in windows XP. That correct or is there a way to upgrade to SP3? In any case, I did try SP3 compatibility in W10 and didn't work.

Comment: I checked. There is no SP 3 for Windows XP 64-bit.  Make another machine Windows XP 32-bit SP3 and try that. Windows XP 64-bit was a bit of an orphan

Comment: I'll give it a try. Is there any hope of making it work in W10?

Comment: You have specifically installed the required version of DX9 on Windows 10?  By default Windows 10 won’t ru. DX9 targeted applications.  DX12 support for DX9 must be programmed by the author of the application.  Since this is an extremely old game make sure your running an 32-bit operating system

Comment: I knew that DX12 supports DX9, but I didn't know I had to program it myself. How do I do that? And no, I have a 64 bit OS.

Comment: Added launch with DirectX9. Didn't work.

Comment: Not much hope of making it work in Windows 10. Try the complete XP SP3 machine

Comment: Tried it in a Windows XP with SP3 and didn't work. results are updated in the post.

Comment: @sartox - You cannot make an existing executable compatible with DX12.  Only the programmer who created the executable can do that.  **A 32-bit executable from 2005 is incompatible with DX12.** I am going to guess it will be impossible to run the program in a virtual machine

Comment: Ok, so using the -dx9 parameter was kind of useless. Anyways, why do you say it will be impossible to run it in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by changing iso and not using the virtual machine. Apparently, it prevented it from running properly.